# Will Java have a way for non-library developers to use extension methods?

Tags: java, extension-methods

C#'s extension methods are great for adding syntactic sugar.  Java extension methods are great for allowing library developers to add methods to their interfaces.

I am a non-library Java developer and know I will reap a lot of benefits from getting new functionality from libraries, but I would still like to have the syntactic sugar capabilities of C# extension methods.

Is this, or will this be possible in future versions of Java?

eg: I would like to add methods to the String class...

```
String data = StringUtils.capitalize("abcd");  // instead of this
String data = "abcd".capitalize()  // I would like to do this
```

Please don't focus on this particular example, I am only showing the class of functionality I want to be able to achieve.

Comment: Java does not have a mechanism for "mortals" to extended classes in this fashion.  There are a few tricks that can be played with certain debugging tools, but they aren't intended for use outside a debug scenario.

Comment: Note that in general there's no hard boundary between "library developers" and "application developers" (at least in the Java world). If a given feature is available for libraries, then it can also be used in applications. Granted, the complexity of some features makes it more likely to be used in libraries. For example: *writing* APIs that make good use of generics in complex scenarios is very hard, so it's usually only done in (reusable) libraries. *using* such APIs is much easier (if the APIs are well-designed).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java does not have this feature, nor is it likely to have it anytime soon.

[Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/) however does have a [very similar feature](http://groovy.codehaus.org/JN3525-MetaClasses), and it also runs on the JVM. Perhaps that's an option.

Comment: Thanks Sean.  I tried Groovy a few years ago (pre Java 7), and found it too slow.  I was able to speed things up by making my code less groovified, but it was still 10x slower.  So I just switched back to Java. I should try groovy again with Java 7 to see if I run into the same issues, but I think I've read that Groovy is still 10x slower than Java, and I can't afford 10x more hardware!

Comment: @BobThule: Groovy got a lot faster these day and interestingly enough, Java 7 played a big role in this (via `invokedynamic`).

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you're thinking of a planned addition to Java 8 that will allow you to add methods, with default implementations, to an *interface* -- so that you can add new methods without breaking all existing code.  This is only of use to you if you control the interface type -- so it would not be of use for `String`, because `String` is not an interface.

Comment: Hi Louis, right, but C#'s extension methods allow adding methods to a class-- it's just syntactic sugar, but it makes for pretty code, and for quicker developments since code completion can offer you the methods.  I believe the JDK developers first modeled the Java extension methods off of C#, but then saw that it didn't solve the issues library developers were facing, and so morphed it into what it is now-- which is a really great solution, but not particularly useful for end developers trying to make their code pretty.

Comment: Eh.  I'm personally very much in favor of the limitations the Java folks put on the Java 8 extension methods -- speaking as a library designer, I have very mixed feelings about end developers being able to add arbitrary methods to a type.

Comment: I think the java 8 extension methods are great, and I would not to lose their functionality. It is a preference thing, and I wouldn't try to say you are wrong if you like having lots of calls to static methods tucked away in utility classes, but I prefer calling methods directly on my objects. I think it is cleaner, more readable, and looks more object oriented. And with most other languages being capable of mixins/traits/extension methods, I'd like to be able to do the same with Java.  What's up with String not having a richer set of member methods? Especially since it is a final class?

Comment: At a certain point, you have so many methods that nobody will actually be able to memorize all the methods on a given class.  I'd rather stop it before that point, and have enough methods there that if I need something not already built in, it's easy to slap together out of what's already provided.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible in Java using compiler plugins like [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org), [Manifold](http://manifold.systems), and [fluent](https://github.com/rogerkeays/fluent). I think it is unlikely that the Java guardians will even include this feature in the core language though. For that, maybe try Kotlin?